# How to set shadow at left right and bottom in UIView in ios Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, shadow

I want shadow at left, right and bottom in view. But Swift 3 shadow offset provide only height or width. I found similar answer see below link it show shadow top left right shadow. I want left right and bottom.

1. see link [little similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40011857/8236655)

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same task as link provided, just change the `BezierPath`.

```
let block1 = UIView(frame: CGRect.init(x: 50, y: 50, width: 300, height: 300))
block1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red

block1.layer.masksToBounds = false
block1.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
block1.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
block1.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.7

let path = UIBezierPath()
path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
// Move to center between two top points instead of bottom
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: block1.frame.size.width/2.0, y: block1.frame.size.height/2.0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: block1.frame.size.width, y: 0.0))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: block1.frame.size.width, y: block1.frame.size.height))
path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: block1.frame.size.height))
path.close()
block1.layer.shadowPath = path.cgPath
```