# How to add shadow only to top and bottom to UIVIEW in swift

Tags: ios, swift

I am new in swift and I am trying to add shadow to UIView.
My code is like this

```
ViewPay.layer.masksToBounds = false
ViewPay.layer.shadowRadius = 2
ViewPay.layer.shadowOpacity = 1
ViewPay.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
ViewPay.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0 , height:2)
```

but it is adding shadow to all side

[image]

How can I add shadow like this

Comment: Is your white view is inside another parent's view? if yes then make a clip to bound true to parent view and set shdowOffset = .zero.

Comment: Is the image you showed the expected result or the output of your code?

Comment: Or use bezier path : https://stackoverflow.com/a/47010380/14733292

Comment: expecting this you will achieve it with use of 2 view.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is, put your `ViewPay` inside a container UIView.

Set your `ViewPay` to leading and trailing edges of container view, and for top and bottom add some padding to show shadow.

Also set container view `clipsToBounds` equals to true.

Answer (score 0):

I hope to help with the solution of your question. In case you wanted something simple to understand, and also following the tips. You create a large container and add the required views. A vertical view of the purple color, another horizontal that would be gray color and in the middle put an image, as I did in the code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {
  
    
     override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
         
        //Big container
        let container = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: self.view.bounds.width * 0.25, y: self.view.bounds.height * 0.5, width: 250, height: 290))
        container.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.addSubview(container)
        
        //Purple view
        let viewContainer = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: container.bounds.midX , y: 0, width: container.bounds.width * 0.89, height: container.bounds.height))

        viewContainer.layer.anchorPoint.x = 1.0

        viewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor(displayP3Red: 158/255, green: 131/255, blue: 178/255, alpha: 1.0)
        viewContainer.layer.cornerRadius = 8
        viewContainer.clipsToBounds = true

        container.addSubview(viewContainer)

        //Gray view
        let viewContainer2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: container.bounds.midX , y: container.bounds.midY, width: container.bounds.width * 0.93, height: container.bounds.height * 0.86))

        viewContainer2.layer.anchorPoint.y = 1.0
        viewContainer2.layer.anchorPoint.x = 1.0


        viewContainer2.backgroundColor = UIColor(white: 0.5, alpha: 0.3)
        viewContainer2.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        viewContainer2.clipsToBounds = true

        container.addSubview(viewContainer2)
        
        //image
        let imageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: container.bounds.midX, y: container.bounds.midY, width: container.bounds.width * 0.90, height: container.bounds.height * 0.90))
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleToFill
        imageView.layer.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 1.0, y: 1.0)
        imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 10
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        imageView.image = UIImage(named: "image name")
        container.addSubview(imageView)

     }
}
```

[image: imagem]