# How to add shadow for 3 sides only with corner radius in swift?

Tags: swift, xcode, shadow

I have a UIView and I want to add shadow for leading, trailing & bottom with corner radius. I have added the function but even of no use.

```swift
extension UIView {
   func drawShadowwithCorner() {
      let layer = self.layer
      layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
      layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 0.2)
      layer.shadowOpacity = 0.2
      layer.shadowRadius = 5
      layer.cornerRadius = 12
   }
}
```

Comment: layer.maskedCorners

Comment: means..........?

Comment: Unclear. What's unsatisfactory about what your code does?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer of [Ryan Pools](https://stackoverflow.com/users/563381/ryan-poolos) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15704163/draw-shadow-only-from-3-sides-of-uiview) should work for you. The topic is similar.